# VueJs Не завершать работу компонента при переходе на другой

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется родительский компонент parent-component в котором через slot происходит переключение между вложенными компонентами, в компоненте child-two-component подключен плагин vue-dropzone, все отлично загружается, но как только перехожу на другую страницу у компонента child-two-component жизненный цикл прерывается и соотвественно отменяется загрузка изображений, пробовал через keep-alive, не работает, я так понял он работает только для дочерних элементов, а если вложенность второго уровня, он вообще не реагирует, подскажите как можно обойти ситуацию?

**пример**

```
<parent-component>
<child-component>
<child-two-component>
дочерний компонент второго уровня
<child-two-component>
</child-component>
</parent-component>
```

Comment: [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) ?

Comment: да, vuejs позволяет же использовать для дочерних элементов <keep-alive>, но у меня получается двойная вложенность, то есть он работает пока я нахожусь в компоненте где подключен child-two-component, как перехожу на другой сразу убивает компонент

Comment: Так все-таки у вас переключаются только child-component в рамках parent-component или внутри него и child-two-component тоже может меняться?